# Filter one HTML select dropdown based on another select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

I have a simple PHP script with a form that has two select fields, both of which are simply numerical values. The script also has a maximum for the sum of the two fields. I'm trying to dynamically filter the second drop down, so that a user cannot select more than the maximum. E.g., if my maximum is 10, the first select dropdown would have 1-10 in it. A user selecting 6 would then only be able to select 0-4 in the second select dropdown.

I know this should be reasonably straightforward, but I'm a total JavaScript/jQuery novice. I *have* searched SO and Google, but I don't understand enough of the examples I've seen to know where to start, let alone figure out how to customise them to my needs. I've provided the code I have already, which clearly doesn't have any of the filtering I need.

Some sample code (assume $maximum defined already):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var max = <?php echo $maximum; ?>;
</script>

<select name="dropdown1" id="dropdown1">
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maximum; $i++)
{   
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';  
}
?>
</select>
<select name="dropdown2" id="dropdown2">
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i <= $maximum; $i++)
{   
    echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';  
}
?>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

I now have the following piece of jquery in it's own .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// var max ??
$("#dropdown1").change(function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
    $("#dropdown2 option").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("selected");
    $("#dropdown2 option").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() > max - selectedVal*1)
            $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

    });       
});
});
```

However, I'm a bit stuck getting $maximum from my PHP script into the jQuery. I figure I have to create a JavaScript variable, but not quite sure how to pass it to the jQuery. I can figure out how to do it if I had the jQuery embedded in the same PHP script, just by echoing it out, but not quite so sure about passing it as a parameter.

Comment: Updated my code based on the comments. However not sure how to pass a variable into the jQuery snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update [code](http://jsfiddle.net/dtAgX/1/) of **legendofawesomeness** for your case

Comment: This is almost bang on what I want, and even better, I think I understand it... Just need to figure out parameter passing for the jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtAgX/) is a working fiddle. And, the relevant jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        var selectedVal = $(this).find("option:selected").val();

        $("#select2 option").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() >= selectedVal)
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

        });
    });
});
```